# Search Console Impressions Issue - Graph pulling incorrect data

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-analytics-4

We are currently on Google Analytics 4 and since we have updated our end to the new tracking code, we seem to have false data on Search Console impressions graph - see attached. [image: search console graph]

You can see at the point we updated the code, the data lost all trends (no longer down at weekends etc)

Got any ideas on what the issue could be?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: This graph is coming directly from Google Search Console, right?   The change in impression data could be a coincidence.  I don't see how your GA tags could possibly affect the data that Google records for impressions.  That happens internally to Google before visitors come to your site.

Comment: Yeah that's right Steven - good points. Any ideas on why the data may have changed?